# Get params from other screen in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My React Js skills are very basic,What I want to get is when I click on a category, I show a list of posts of the category selected in a new screen in this case is PostsScreen.

The problem is that i get the itemId null.

I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

These are my screens and the routes component

**Categories Screen**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { NavigationActions, DrawerNavigator,  StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import{Dimensions, Button, View, SafeAreaView, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default class WGoals extends Component {
static navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Categories'
    };

navigateToScreen = (route, params) => () => {
const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
  routeName: route,
  params: params
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
}

constructor(props)
  {
super(props);
this.state = { 
isLoading: true,
  }
}

  render() {

    return (

<Container style={styles.background_general}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.navigateToScreen('PostsScreen', itemId = '1')} >
                <Text>Category 1</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.navigateToScreen('PostsScreen', itemId = '2')} >
                <Text>Category 2</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
</Container>      
    );
  }
}
```

**Posts Screen**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { NavigationActions, DrawerNavigator,  StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import{Dimensions, View, SafeAreaView, FlatList, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

export default class Posts extends Component {
static navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Posts'
};

  render() {

    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    const itemId = params ? params.itemId : null;

    return (

<Container style={styles.background_general}>

<Text>Details Screen</Text>
<Text>itemId: {JSON.stringify(itemId)}</Text>

</Container>

    );
  }
    }
```

**Routes**

```
import React from 'react';
import CategoriesScreen from '../screens/Categories';
import PostsScreen from '../screens/Posts';
import SideMenu from './SideMenu';
import {DrawerNavigator, StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation'

const navigationOptions = {
  navigationOptions: {
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#f39c12',
    },
    headerTitleStyle: {
      textAlign: 'center',
      alignSelf: 'center',
      fontSize: 20,
      color: '#fff',
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
  }
};

const leftIcon = (navigation, icon) => <Icon
  name={icon}
  style={{marginLeft: 20}}
  size={20}
  color="white"
  onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}
/>;

const rightIcon = (navigation, icon) => <Icon
  name={icon}
  style={{marginLeft: 20}}
  size={30}
  color="white"
  onPress={() => navigation.navigate('CategoriesScreen')}
/>;

const CategoriesScreenStack = StackNavigator (
{
  Categories: {
    screen: CategoriesScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      drawerIcon: ({tintColor}) => (<Icon name="home" size={24} style={{color: '#f39c12'}} />),
      headerLeft: leftIcon(navigation, 'menu')
    })
  }
  },
  navigationOptions
);

const PostsScreenStack = StackNavigator(
  {
    PostsScreen: {
      screen: PostsScreen,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (<Icon name="user" size={24} style={{ color: tintColor }} />),
        headerLeft: leftIcon(navigation, 'menu')
      })
    }
  },
  navigationOptions
);

export default DrawerNavigator({
  CategoriesScreen: {
    screen: CategoriesScreenStack
  },
  PostsScreen: {
    screen: PostsScreenStack
      },
    }, {
  contentComponent: SideMenu,
  drawerWidth: width * .7,
  drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
  drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
  drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle',
});
```

Comment: Try to narrow the problem down to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  This will make it easier for people to help.

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass `itemId` in an object to `navigateToScreen`, since you are accessing params as an object (`params.itemId)` in `WorkoutsGoalsList`, currently it is undefined.

Also, `onPress` expects a function reference. As it is now, you are actually calling the function so `this.navigateGateToScreen` will be called on every render. Check out the [bind documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), bind allows you to create a new function with a specific list of arguments:

```
render () {
  return (
    <Container style={styles.background_general}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={this.onPress.bind(this, '1')}
      >
        <Text>Category 1</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={this.onPress.bind(this, '2')}
      >
        <Text>Category 2</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </Container>
  );
};

onPress = (id) => {
  this.navigateToScreen('PostsScreen', { itemId: id })
};
```

You also do not need to curry your `navigateToScreen` function:

```
navigateToScreen = (route, params) => {   // remove curry here
  const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
    routeName: route,
    params: params,
  });
  this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
};
```

Your props will look something like this:

```
this.props = {
  navigation: {
    state: {
      params: {
        itemId: '1',
      }
    }
  }
};
```

It's less than optimal to bind in render because a new function will be created on every render call. A better way to structure the code is to create a dedicated component and pass an `itemId` and `onPress` function:

**WGoals**

```
export default class WGoals extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Categories',
  };

  navigateToScreen = (route, params) => {
    const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: route,
      params: params,
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container style={styles.background_general}>
        <Category name='Category1' onPress={this.navigateToScreen} itemId='1' />
        <Category name='Category2' onPress={this.navigateToScreen} itemId='2' />
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

**Category**

```
export default class Category extends Component {
  render () {
    const { name } = this.props;

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this.handlePress}
        >
          <Text>{name}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }

  handlePress = () => {
    const { itemId, onPress } = this.props;

    onPress('PostsScreen', { itemId: itemId });
  }
}
```

In PostsScreens, you need to render `itemId` in a string or you can render the value of the variable by wrapping it in curly brackets (`{itemId}`). Below, I'm rendering it as a string and inserting the value of `itemId` into the string. Check out the [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) docs for more info on the syntax:

```
export default class Posts extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Posts',
  };

  render() {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    const itemId = params ? params.itemId : null;

    return (
      <Container style={styles.background_general}>
        <Text>'Details Screen'</Text>
        <Text>`itemId: ${itemId}`</Text>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I test it, but when i clicked in the category no respond

Comment: i want something like this but the result in the diferent screen https://reactnativecode.com/show-json-listview-click-item-value-on-another-activity/

Comment: Updated, remove curry in navigateToScreen.

Comment: I get this error "import and export may only appear at the top level"

Comment: Did you place the Category component in a separate file and import it in WGoals? My fault that wasn't clear.

Comment: No, i will try now

Comment: I test it but, when i click not redirect to PostsScreen

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle with the basic functionality working. You can check the console to see that navigateToScreen is being called correctly and the params are being passed correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/174839/

Comment: in PostsScreen i see this error "Can't find variable itemId"

Comment: Updated. You need to render the itemId as a string.

Comment: I try but still not working :/ this is my PostsScreen: 
export default class PostsScreen extends Component {
static navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Posts'
};
  render() {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    const itemId = params ? params.itemId : null;
    return (
<Container style={styles.background_general}>
<Text>Details Screen</Text>
<Text>itemId: ${itemId}</Text>
</Container>  
    );
  }
}

Comment: Only show this result : (itemId: $) without the value

Comment: you can solve it for me by TeamViewer (I pay for it)

Comment: What is being rendered currently? Can you insert a breakpoint or console.log(params) and see what that equals?

Comment: i insert this console.log('Params: '+params) and the result is undefined

Comment: I resolve it, the problem is im using the drawernavigator and this not support params, any idea how to user both stack and drawer navigation?, thanks for your time +1

Comment: I resolve it , thanks , now i have new problem with columns check my question please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49845628/how-to-render-items-in-two-columns-in-react-native